# Work-around for scrolling in MS Edge version that has bug?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, smooth-scrolling

The current (06-2018) version of Microsoft Edge, 40.15063.0.0, has a bad bug preventing dynamic scrolling.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15534521/

> Edge browser not work with scrollTo method

The `scrollTo` and `scroll` functions appear to be broken and `scrollTop` doesn't work either (except maybe for `0`). Are there any work-arounds for now?

Comment: Does the [comment further down the page work?](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15534521/#comment-1) or does it not fit your use case?  I see the commentor says it won't work for scrolling to the actual top.

Comment: Using `scrollTop` as a work-around does not seem to work.